# Outlook 2010 Rule to forward emails with attachment at specific time

Tags: vba, email, outlook

On a Daily basis, I receive hourly emails that includes attachment and has a subject in the following format `2014-02-13 emailAlert`.

Is there rule/VBA I can follow to `forward` this email `with attachment` to someone automatically `everyday` at a `specific time`.

It should forward only the `newest` email with the subject `emailAlert` at that specific point in time.

Appreciate if you guys can help :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a rule in Outlook and then assign a VBA macro to forward the incoming email if it meets your conditions. The macro sub should look like the following one:

```
public sub test(mail as MailItem)
  ' do whatever you need here
end sub
```

where the mail object represents the incoming email.

The [Forward](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865399(v=office.15).aspx) method of the MailItem class executes the Forward action for an item and returns the resulting copy as a MailItem object. For example, the following sample illustrates how to use the Forward method:

```
Sub RemoveAttachmentBeforeForwarding()  
  Dim myinspector As Outlook.Inspector  
  Dim myItem As Outlook.MailItem  
  Dim myattachments As Outlook.Attachments 

  Set myinspector = Application.ActiveInspector  
  If Not TypeName(myinspector) = "Nothing" Then  
    Set myItem = myinspector.CurrentItem.Forward  
    Set myattachments = myItem.Attachments   
    While myattachments.Count > 0  
      myattachments.Remove 1  
    Wend  
    myItem.Display  
    myItem.Recipients.Add "Eugene Astafiev"  
    myItem.Send  
  Else  
    MsgBox "There is no active inspector."  
  End If 
End Sub
```

The [DeferredDeliveryTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869452(v=office.15).aspx) property of the MailItem class allows to set a Date indicating the date and time the mail message is to be delivered.

Finally, you may find the [Getting Started with VBA in Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814736(v=office.14).aspx) article helpful.